# Why can I see CSS2DObject after the camera is behind CSS2DObject?

Tags: three.js

I added CSS2DObject to the scene.

```
self.labelDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
self.labelDiv.className = 'label';      
self.labelDiv.innerHTML = textshow; 
self.label = new THREE.CSS2DObject( self.labelDiv );            
self.label.position.set(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);   
this.scene.add(lab);
```

The effect is as follows：
[label1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tE1A.png)

I moved the camera forward until I couldn't see the model, but the label was displayed again. 
[label2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNRt5.png)

What is the reason? How to avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: This bug was fixed in release r.103.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Renderer can't do clipping like the WebGL renderer so it relies on frustum culling to get rid of objects...

Check if any errors /warnings are showing in console?

Check you're using the latest THREE.js?

Make sure frustumCulling is not disabled on your objects?

Make sure your css objects have some kind of boundingbox or boundingsphere perhaps?